# Where do I find spinner Icon in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I learned that it is possible to render system images like so:

```
Image(nsImage: NSImage(imageLiteralResourceName: NSImage.addTemplateName))
```

But there seem to be no corresponding template name for spinner:
[image]

Do I have to use custom svg?

Comment: It is not an image/icon, it is `NSProgressIndicator` control

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Xcode 12

it's just a simple view.

```
ProgressView()
```

Currently, it's defaulted to `CircularProgressViewStyle` but you can manually set the style of it by adding the following modifer:

```
.progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
```

Also, the style could be anything that conforms to `ProgressViewStyle`

---

## Xcode 11

You can use `NSProgressIndicator` directly in SwiftUI:

## Implementation

```
struct ProgressIndicator: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    typealias TheNSView = NSProgressIndicator
    var configuration = { (view: TheNSView) in }
    
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<ProgressIndicator>) -> NSProgressIndicator {
        TheNSView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSProgressIndicator, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<ProgressIndicator>) {
        configuration(nsView)
    }
}
```

## Sample Usage

```
var body: some View {
    ProgressIndicator {
        $0.controlTint = .blueControlTint
    }
}
```

You can replace `TheNSView` with any other `NSView` you need to use in SwiftUI.

Comment: To follow-up to this answer, here's an example SwiftUI wrapper around `NSProgressIndicator` from an open-source project: https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX/blob/73ee6bfb44e76ae08a146e7e575176743f0615e9/Sources/Intramodular/Progress/ActivityIndicator.swift#L56-L75

Comment: Many thanks. From your answer I learned not only how to make a spinner, but how to use NSViews in general.

Answer (score 0):

This icon cannot get as Image.

I have add my source code form my swift ui class:
[ActivityIndicator](https://gist.github.com/zandercodes/a0cb52565b07a5b24679896cb02e1bfa)

Comment: the topic is tagged [macOS]

Comment: Sry, yes this code is Only for iOS, iPad-OS and tvOS.